# Best way to display a popup container with lots of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core

So I am developing a website (ASP.Net Core MVC) and I am trying to display a container, with potentially lots of data inside, as soon as I click on a Button see the image.

[image]

Each row has its add button. There will be only around 10-30 buttons on a page at once. As soon as you click on such a button the showed pop up should display next to the clicked button. As you can see in the picture the pop up may contain a lot of data itself. And this data might differ from each row.

### What is the best approach?

1. Placing each these pop ups already in the HTML and on click `display: block` and `display: none` when hovering away.
2. With jQuery and using the append method and summon the popup next to it and remove it after hovering away.

Or is there even a different approach to this?

### Why am I asking?

I am concerned in terms of performance and loading time.

Comment: `I am concerned in terms of performance and loading time.` have you measured performance? this SO-question page has ~ 1500 dom elements and loads/is quite fast, you worry about adding 30 ?

Comment: @birdspider This is a pretty old question by now. Anyhow IIRC I wasn't aware of the actual performance and techniques available. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Make a request on click and load only the necessary data if concerned about loading times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion there are downsides and upsides to both approaches.

For approach 1:
This will cause a slower initial load time but will be faster to use than approach 2 when it's loaded.

Approach 2:
A downside to this is jQuery needs to be loaded for this. I don't know if you use it throughout your project. But just for this, it would be a little bit overkill.
However initial loadtime can be fast and you could use AJAX to load each data when it's clicked.

I'm not a programmer with 10 years of experience, so this answer is pure my opinion and what I think about it.

Hope this opens a discussion!